trubels builds in Unity 2022
truble console - CommandinvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.Hello, when I create a project, the Build error error appears Gradle build error. For more information, see the console. OK, the error in the console is below
E:12022.3.42f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayerOpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "E:12022.3.42f1\EditoriData\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\ToolsigradieVlibigradie-launcher-7.5.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradieMain
"-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
I wanted to delete something, well, I thought it was not necessary to take risks, but there is nothing really on the Internet about my mistake, help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
